# How to set TCP based Load Balancer as origin to Cloud CDN?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-cdn

When adding origin to Cloud CDN, only HTTP(S) Load Balancer appears in the options. While the TCP/UDP Load Balancer doesn't.

[image]

Is it possible to set TCP/UDP Load Balancer as origin to Google Cloud CDN? How?

In my case, I really need TCP/UDP origin since the LB is managed by nginx (K8S Nginx Ingress, not K8S GCE Ingress). The same issue also need to be tackled when using Istio Gateway.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn) doc

> Cloud CDN uses HTTP(S) load balancing as the origin for cacheable
>   content. You must use HTTP(S) load balancing as the origin of content
>   cached by Cloud CDN.

At the moment, it is not possible to use a TCP load balancer.

You can file a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com) to have this implemented. You should check to see if a similar feature request has been filled first, & upvote/star it, as the feature requests which impact the most people will have a better chance of being implemented.